# How to skip null values in PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

I have a query in database table name "c_hw_day" in postgresql

```
select  pr.c_period_id,
        unnest(array_agg_mult(array[hd.wd1,hd.wd2,hd.wd3,hd.wd4,hd.wd5,hd.wd6,hd.wd7,hd.wd8,hd.wd9,hd.wd10,hd.hd1,hd.hd2,hd.hd2,hd.hd3,hd.hd4,hd.hd5,hd.hd6,hd.hd7,hd.hd8,hd.hd9,hd.hd10])) as wd_hd 
from    c_hw_day hd
  left join c_period pr on (hd.c_period_id = pr.c_period_id) 
group by 1
```

result like

| ID | Weekend |
| --- | --- |
| 1000051 | 2018-11-30 00:00:00 |
| 1000051 |  |
| 1000051 |  |
| 1000051 | 2018-12-07 00:00:00 |
| 1000051 |  |
| 1000051 |  |
| 1000051 |  |
| 1000051 | 2018-12-14 00:00:00 |

I want to skip the null value like

| ID | Weekend |
| --- | --- |
| 1000051 | 2018-11-30 00:00:00 |
| 1000051 | 2018-12-07 00:00:00 |
| 1000051 | 2018-12-14 00:00:00 |

Comment: `unnest()` together with `array_agg()` looks quite suspicious in the SELECT list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would would not do this using arrays.  I would just use a lateral join:

```
select  pr.c_period_id, wd_hd
from c_hw_day hd left join
     c_period pr 
     on hd.c_period_id = pr.c_period_id lateral join
     (values (hd.wd1, hd.wd2, hd.wd3, hd.wd4, hd.wd5, hd.wd6, hd.wd7, hd.wd8, hd.wd9, hd.wd10, hd.hd1, hd.hd2, hd.hd2, hd.hd3, hd.hd4, hd.hd5, hd.hd6, hd.hd7, hd.hd8, hd.hd9, hd.hd10
     ) v(hd)
where hd is not null;
```

This logic is much clearer.  Without the outer `group by`, I suspect it is faster as well.

Answer (score 1):

the most lasiest way - put your query into subquery
if you don't have a lot of data will be ok

```
select * from (
    select  pr.c_period_id,
           unnest(array_agg_mult(array[hd.wd1,hd.wd2,hd.wd3,hd.wd4,hd.wd5,hd.wd6,hd.wd7,hd.wd8,hd.wd9,hd.wd10,hd.hd1,hd.hd2,hd.hd2,hd.hd3,hd.hd4,hd.hd5,hd.hd6,hd.hd7,hd.hd8,hd.hd9,hd.hd10])) as wd_hd 
    from    c_hw_day hd
      left join c_period pr on (hd.c_period_id = pr.c_period_id) 
    group by 1
)q1
where wd_hd is not null
```